Access tomcat logs via browser
Good morning,
We have some machines with Apache + Tomcat offering web applications.
We want to give access the developers to view the tomcat logs, but we dont want they cant access the machine (ssh), so we need to offer the Tomcat logs vía brower (only read the logs, and if require a login its better).
Is there some easy and "light" solution to achieve this?
Best regards

I would think a super simple servlet could do this pretty easily.  Depending on your configuration login may be simple or a bit more challenging.

Well, you just need to setup an "Alias" or an additional virtual host pointing to the folder those logs are stored in on the server side. That should allow access. You certainly should add some form of authorization scheme though, since those logs contain quite a bunch of information that might be of interest for shady people ...
